# What is wrong with these .NET Controls?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, user-controls, webforms

Code :

```
foreach (HtmlGenericControl div in panelCategorieGuida.Controls.OfType<HtmlGenericControl>())
{
    HiddenField hf = div.Controls.OfType<HtmlGenericControl>().LastOrDefault();
}
```

it says "that I can't implicitly convert HtmlGenericControl to HiddenField". Also if I wrote `(HiddenField)div.Controls.OfType<HtmlGenericControl>().LastOrDefault()` it doesnt works.

The last element of div (which is a HtmlGenericControl) is always a HiddenField element.

Why? Where am I wrong?

Comment: ... do you know the difference between explicit and implicit cast?

Comment: When you want to find the last HiddenField, why don't you use `div.Controls.OfType<HiddenField>()` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't it be like

```
HiddenField hf = div.Controls.OfType<HiddenField>().LastOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (var div in panelCategorieGuida.Controls.OfType<HtmlGenericControl>())
{
    var hf = div.Controls.OfType<HiddenField>().LastOrDefault();
}
```

Your initial code just did the following:

- filter the list to elements, which are type of `HtmlGenericControl`
- take the last (or default)
- cast it to `HiddenField` (implicit and/or explicit)

Now: Unless the last element, which is of type `HtmlGenericControl`, isn't a real `HiddenField` you'll get the invalid cast-exception. You might filter the elements to `HiddenField` (as I did it), or rather take this code:

```
var hf = div.Controls.OfType<HtmlGenericControl>().LastOrDefault() as HiddenField;
```

Which is a "safe cast" ...

Answer (score 1):

I think @Pranay Rana is right. 
If you explicit cast is also failed, I think you need check whether the element you want is a hidden field. 
Also, your code has some problems. You should always do some validation before you carry on. If not, maybe in test stage, your code running well. But it may encounter some errors later in production.

Answer (score 0):

If you **know** it's a HiddenField, this should work:

```
HiddenField hf = div.Controls.LastOrDefault() as HiddenField;
```

Comment: he believes to *know* , as he does a cast ... `as` and a cast just differ in the safe-manner - and nothing else! your solution is correct, but the description is wrong!

Answer (score 0):

i think you should first check if it's a hidden field or not like this

```
if( div.Controls.OfType<HtmlGenericControl>().LastOrDefault() is HiddenField)
{
  /// rest of the processing code 
}
```

**which might resolve your problem, because the element you are getting might not be hiddenfield element**